# Fragment within FragmentTabHost view lost onBackPressed Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have created a application. Following is scenario before I explain problem.

I have Activity A which has multiple fragments such as F1,F2,F3 etc.

Now for F1 fragment I have implemented FragmentTabHost with three Fragments F11,F12,F13 fragment views. On tab is working fine for this.

But today i noticed one problem.
Say I am inside F1 I show three fragment tabs F11,F12,F13. User can switch between tabs and it works fine.

Problem is say i goto Fragment F13 from F11 by pressing tab. It shows F13 fragment successfully.

However when I click Back Button on menu it goes back F11 fragment but empty screen is shown means F11 view is not shown..

This is my F1 fragment code implementing FragmentTabHost:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container,
                false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // realtabcontent = (FrameLayout) rootView
        // .findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView
                .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
                R.layout.home_fragment);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        View tabView = createTabView(getActivity(), "Featured");
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("featured").setIndicator(tabView);

        mTabHost.addTab(spec, FeaturedHomeTab.class, null);

        tabView = createTabView(getActivity(), "Top");
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("top").setIndicator(tabView);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec, TopHomeTab.class, null);

        tabView = createTabView(getActivity(), "New");
        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("new").setIndicator(tabView);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec, NewHomeTab.class, null);
        onTabChanged("featured");
        return rootView;
    }
```

So this is main code with three fragments and when i back from one fragment to previous fragment in tabhost view disappears.

What can be problem. Please help.

Comment: it has to do with your attaching and detaching of your fragments..so if you cool to post it.might help

Comment: what you want to post

Comment: no you are supose to post codes right? so i am saying post the code relating what i said..

Comment: check now i have updated code

Comment: i need to handle this onbackpress somehow but i dont know how..

Comment: I have 2 questions: What makes you sure that you go to fragment F11 when you press back. Can you show us how you attach fragment F1 in actiivty? I guess that when you press back fragment F1 detaches from activity and you see black screen, to prove this try adding a color to your activity layout and fragment F1 layout

Comment: actually I solved it in ParentActivity for main fragment F1 onBackPress event to check if current fragment is F1 then i am showing option to exit application.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs aren't meant to participate in temporal navigation (which is what back nav is for) because they represent content at same level of hierarchy.

In case of fragments, the back nav usually pops the back stack. There is a caveat that back nav doesn't pops sub (child) fragments first. So, the fragments added to Activity are removed on back, this includes the entire tabs fragment (along with its child fragments).